# Ansible email Module " Need to send email to only once"

Tags: ansible

In my playbook, one of the task is to send email notification once a file is updated. I am getting email notifications, since I have 5 hosts entries in my hostile its sending 5 different emails. I just want my playbook to send only one email. Can someone please help with it

```
 - name: Send Email after Adding the new conf
   local_action: mail
    host="localhost"
    port=25
    subject="New Config Added"
    body="New config has been added in reference to {{ticketNo}}"
    from="myemail"
    to="destination-email"
    charset=utf8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [run_once](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once) – this way task will be executed only once no matter how many host are there in the play.